# Jekyll installation isn't showing index page upon navigation

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have recently made a foray into the Jekyll world. I'm currently exploring this on a local Apache2 server running Bootstrap 3 with a simple responsive layout.

**Installation Summary**
I just installed ruby, ruby-dev, gcc, make and all appropriate gems. The Jekyll installation guide was great to get it installed and such. I went ahead and create a new blog, 'sudo jekyll new blog' in /var/www/html. Now as, /var/www/html/blog.

**Installation Directory**
about.md
_config.yaml
Gemfile
Gemfile.block
.gitignore
index.md
_posts
.sass-cache
_site/

**Post Installation Configuration**
I've edited the _config.yaml file to establish base directories and such, everything looks appropriate.

I fire up the Jekyll instance via: sudo exec jykll serve, which is currently producing.

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
      rouge (~> 1.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Configuration file: /var/www/html/blog/_config.yml
Configuration file: /var/www/html/blog/_config.yml
            Source: /var/www/html/blog
       Destination: /var/www/html/blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.458 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/var/www/html/blog'
Configuration file: /var/www/html/blog/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/blog/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

*Issue*
The issue that I am having is that when I navigate to localhost/blog, instead of seeing a 'homepage' or index, all I'm seeing is the directory structure as noted above. It's as if the index file isn't rendering or such. However, if I click into _site/, I get something that looks a bit like a classic landing page for the sample post.

*Question*
What am I missing? Did I mis-configure something? Is this expected behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you go to `http://localhost:4000/blog` instead of `http://localhost/blog`? You don't need Apache to run a development version of Jekyll. `jekyll serve` launches a development server.

Comment: It works @ localhost:4000/blog! So, how do I get it to just work via localhost/blog? Because, at my website I'm just running a simple bootstrap landing page and I want blog/Jekyll to effectively be a sub-component of the main site.

Comment: `jekyll build` will "compile" your site into a static HTML into the `_site` folder. You can then just copy all the files from that directory it into the `blog` directory served by Apache.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How do I make it so that I don't have to perform that manual operation? I'd rather just write the content and have it dynamically available. Or, am I just stuck?

Comment: I guess it depends on your setup. For example, I use jekyll for http://gaston.life Locally, I use `jekyll server`, which autoloads changes for me. But when deploying to production, I use a script that builds the site and pushes the generated static HTML to S3, where my site is served: https://github.com/gjorquera/Gaston.Life/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Comment: Thanks Gaston. I'll have to explore further. It shouldn't be that big of a deal to just 'cp' the files for now just to get the entire thing bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking at the generated files without a web server.

You can run a webserver at the folder that contains *_config.yml*, just to see that everything goes fine, then you need a "real" web server to serve your pages: `$ jekyll serve`

After running `jekyll serve` you will be able to access your website at: http://localhost:4000

Comment: Thanks for this. It does answer the question.